# Audi MMI - Sound Focus: Symmetric vs Driver

Tags: audi, mmi

I have an Audi A6 C6 4F2 with (I believe) a 2G MMI Basic (Red color only).

If you go into the sound options; you can see there are two settings under a 'Sound focus'

- **Symmetric**
- **Driver**

Now with **Symmetric** selected, it seems like the sound is coming from every speaker without any of them louder than the other in my opinion.

When you select **Driver** it feels like the sound is coming from the front-center. As if there were speakers in the center of the windshield.

I personally prefer the Symmetric one, but what is the actual difference and what really happens in terms of speaker volume?

I couldn't find much online regarding this subject..